# Smooth scroling in chart with datetime x axis

Tags: c#, datetime, scroll, charts, axis

I have this simple graph plotted in a chart. On the X-axis the values are `DateTime` values.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<double> valuelist = new List<double>();
    List<DateTime> timelist = new List<DateTime>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // fill the lists with values
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            double value = Math.Sin(i/20.0);
            valuelist.Add(value);
            timelist.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i + 2));
        }

        // add the Values to the chart
        for (int i = 0; i < valuelist.Count; i++)
        {
            this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timelist[i], valuelist[i]);
        }

        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM-hh:mm";

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = timelist.Max().ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = timelist.Min().ToOADate();


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        DateTime intervall = timelist.Min().AddHours(3);


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum, intervall.ToOADate());


        // disable zoom-reset button 
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

        // set scrollbar small change to blockSize 
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = intervall.ToOADate();
    }

}
```

My problem is that I cannot get the scrollbar to move smoothly. When I plot only the Y-Values and use just `double` values for the `AxisX.Maximum`, `AxisX.Minimum`, `AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom` and for `AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize` it works like a charm. But as soon as I use `DateTime` for the X-Values I can only scroll in steps. Does someone know how to surpass this? I have the feeling that this piece of code is the obstacle:

```
// set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = intervall.ToOADate();
```

EDIT:

The Interval for the X-Axis is automatic, the range is set by the ZoomLevel of `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom`. Here is a picture:

[image]

EDIT 2:

The Values for the X-Axis are DateTime-Values simulating a sampling of 1 value every minute:

```
timelist.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i + 2));
```

Because it is a lot of values I did not set an interval.
The code is posted this way, so that it can be copied as it is and run right away to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scrolling interval is wrong.

It should not be the start of your data but the step you want to go when scrolling.

Looks like you want to scroll by 3 hours?

Here is what you do:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 3;
```

If you wanted to use a `DateTime.ToOADate` double to achieve the same you need it to start at the first day of the `DataTime` data type (`0`aka 'dawn of time' aka `1899-12-30`) and then add 3 hours:

```
 DateTime interval = DateTime.FromOADate(0).AddHours(3);
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = interval.ToOADate();
```

To allow dragging the lift smoothly this may work better than setting the `SmallScrollSize`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType  =DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 60;
```

Use your unit and numbers! This will only work if you **don't set** the `SmallScrollMinSize`.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately the same result. I cannot drag the scrollbutton and slide smoothly through the graph, only in steps.

Comment: I actually want to scroll fluently, which works when I don't mess around with date-time in the x-axis values. The zoom windows is set by `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom` and is supposed to slide within this interval

Comment: You need to tell us more about the values in your chart! Dragging the lift can only move by at least one pixel * the scale.  Are you sure about the steps? They could be your DataPoints but also jumping Axis Labels. Really hard to tell without knowing more, esp. without seeing an image. Did you set the Axis.Interval???

Comment: I have something like that also in mind. But I cannot figure out how to get around this stepping. I edited my post. The code can be copied and compiled as it is. It will run and show it self. The data is entirely generated by the code

Comment: Good. There are a few german names still in the posted code ;-) - Try to __replace__ the SmallScrollSize settings with this `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 60;`

Comment: Brilliant!!! That works! please include this into your answer!! `SmallScrollMinSizeType` is the key! If I go down to `DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds` it is even really fluent! `SmallScrollMinSize` seems to be irrelevant and can be commented out (and I changed all the german names :-))

Comment: `SmallScrollMinSize` still controls the scroll amount when click on a scrolling arrow. Glad to help.. Gut' Nacht ;-)

Comment: ah good to know, did not consider the arrows because in reality there are much more values, and one would get crazy clicking. Thank you again so much! I wouldn't have come up with this solution on my own. Gut's Nächtle :)